# Rounding off number shows different result on positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript

I've rounding the number into 2 decimal places:

```
function round(num, decimals)
{
    var factor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return Math.round(num * factor) / factor;
}  round(-5.255, 2);
-5.25
function round(num, decimals)
{
    var factor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return Math.round(num * factor) / factor;
}  round(5.255, 2);
5.26
```

But I've observed that it is giving different result when it is positive or negative.

Why is this happening and How can this be corrected?

Comment: Do you know how rounding works with negative numbers? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/rules-for-rounding-positive-and-negative-numbers The result is what is expected.

Comment: @epascarello yes so how can I round down if negative?

Comment: Well if you want to round incorrectly, you would need to change the number to positive and than add the negative back on.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/rules-for-rounding-positive-and-negative-numbers

Comment: @epascarello: Good solution. But I almost did not upvote, because of the term "Incorrectly". There are different use-cases, and one is not more correct than the other. The link you provided yourself lists a good number of rounding policies.

Comment: lazy solution, works every time on 2 decimal places...round(-5.255, 2) -.01 :)

Comment: If i remembrer my maths courses (quite long ago...), 0,1,2,3&4 round to the nearest smaller value, 5,6,7,8,&9 round to the nearest greater value. 5.26 is greater than 5.255. So is -5.25 greater than -5.255.

Comment: @fpierrat hmm true that except you don't need to add it in if above - .49--

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

> If the fractional portion of number is 0.5 or greater, the argument is rounded to the next higher integer.

So when the fraction is exactly `0.5`, it rounds up. For a negative number, this means it rounds closer to 0, for a positive number it rounds away from 0. So `-0.5` rounds to `0`, while `0.5` rounds to `1`.

If you want symmetric rounding, you can get the number's absolute value, round that, then convert it back to the original sign:

```
function symmetricRound(num) {
    return Math.sign(num) * Math.round(Math.abs(num));
}
```

[`Math.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) is an EcmaScript 6 addition. If you're on an older browser, use the polyfill from the documentation.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot find function sign in object [object Math].

Answer (score 0):

1. Why: 
   If i remembrer my maths courses (quite long ago...), 0,1,2,3&4 round to the nearest smaller value, 5,6,7,8,&9 round to the nearest greater value. 5.26 is greater than 5.255. So is -5.25 greater than -5.255.
2. How:
   If you really need to have a behavior that is the same in absolute value, why not round the absolute value, then apply a "-1" factor if original value is <0?